# Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Unable to enter a duplicate key

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I don't know how to solve this error!
I'm trying to configure an automation, but when I try to save the SQL query I get the error: The query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Unable to enter a duplicate key.
This is the SQL I'm trying to automate:

```
SELECT jh.AccountID,
       jh.Nome AS Nome_cliente,
       jh.Consentimento_Email,
       jh.Email,
       jh.Numero_mensagem,
       jh.Data_ultima_compra,
       jh.Vai_receber_mensagem,

        CASE WHEN a.Numero_material='4001206' OR a.Numero_material='4001207' OR a.Numero_material='4001743' OR 
                  a.Numero_material='4002793' OR a.Numero_material='4005220' OR a.Numero_material='4005845' OR 
                  a.Numero_material='4005846' OR a.Numero_material='4012098' OR a.Numero_material='4015848' OR 
                  a.Numero_material='4016587' OR a.Numero_material='4001701' OR a.Numero_material='4013535' OR 
                  a.Numero_material='4016512' OR a.Numero_material='4002322' 
        THEN 1 
    END AS Template_email

 FROM [jornada_hipertensao] jh 
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        mv.AccountID,
        mh.Numero_material
    FROM Master_Vendas_Prd mv 
        INNER JOIN Master_ItensVendas_New_Prd miv ON miv.OrderId = mv.OrderID 
        INNER JOIN Medicamentos_Hipertensao mh on mh.Numero_material = miv.MaterialNumber
    )a 
    ON a.AccountID = jh.AccountID

WHERE jh.Consentimento_Email=1
```

Structure of "jornada_hipertensao"
[image]

Structure of Master_Vendas_Prd
[image]

Structure of Master_ItensVendas_New_Prd
[image]

Structure of Medicamentos_Hipertensao
[image]

I got lost, from what I researched this error occurs when the source of the query does not have a primary key, but the destination does.. but I'm using several tables... I don't know how to solve it, I tried to remove the primary key from the destination base but it is mandatory to have the PK in the destination base....

Destination base:
[image]

thank you who can help

Comment: What's criteria for picking one of the duplicate AccountID rows if they are returned from your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is to partition by the primary key of the target DE, but the criteria to order the duplicates (`by newID()` below) so the one you want is picked is the key question.

```sql
SELECT top 1 with ties
  jh.AccountID
, jh.Nome AS Nome_cliente
, jh.Consentimento_Email
, jh.Email
, jh.Numero_mensagem
, jh.Data_ultima_compra
, jh.Vai_receber_mensagem
, case 
    when a.Numero_material in ('4001206','4002793','4005846','4016587','4016512','4001207','4005220','4012098','4001701','4002322','4001743','4005845','4015848','4013535' THEN 1 
  end AS Template_email
 FROM [jornada_hipertensao] jh 
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      mv.AccountID
    , mh.Numero_material
    FROM Master_Vendas_Prd mv 
    INNER JOIN Master_ItensVendas_New_Prd miv ON miv.OrderId = mv.OrderID 
    INNER JOIN Medicamentos_Hipertensao mh on mh.Numero_material = miv.MaterialNumber
) a ON a.AccountID = jh.AccountID
WHERE jh.Consentimento_Email=1
order by row_number() over (partition by a.accountId order by newID())
```

Comment: I tested your sql to see if it worked and I'm getting:  
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Anyway, I'm starting to understand my mistake. @Adam Spriggs

Comment: I'd recommend using a Query Activity instead of Query Studio.

Comment: Thank you! You were right about running out of query studio :) @Adam Spriggs